# How do I center an h3 tag above the audio player?

Tags: html, css

I want to center the h3 tag which reads "my favourite song ↓" to be right above the audio player and centered, not fully to the left and not right above the audio player. I know I can remove the br line to get it closer together, but I don't want to simply use padding, I want to be sure it's centered correctly.

```html
<hr>
<h3>my <u><i>favourite</i></u> song ↓</h3>
<br>
<audio controls>
    <source src="audio/xyz.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<hr>
```

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: I tried asking ChatGPT since I had no idea and it recommended me to put both the h3 tag and audio player into a div and then making it a class, and inside the class putting     
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center; but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried CSS Flex Box?

Comment: I haven't used that, no.
I'm not sure how to implement that into the code too, though.
I've only ever done html a couple years ago and haven't ever gotten far enough to get past these simple problems.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do that using CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <hr>
    <h3>my <u><i>favourite</i></u> song ↓</h3>
    <br>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="audio/xyz.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <hr>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Simply is great, but please explain your answer. How is flexbox working here?

Comment: Flexbox justifies the element align. align-items property justifies vertical alignment but horizontal alignment when set flex-direction: column;

Answer (score -1):

Using Flexbox and grouping elements into hierarchical divs you can keep the objects organized in space. This [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) have a good explanation about flexbox.

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #2ac93f;
}

.content-header {
    background-color: #9ac93f;
    padding: 2px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.content-body {
    display: flex;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

    <div class="content-header">
        <h3>my <u><i>favourite</i></u> song ↓</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="content-body">
        <audio controls>
            <source src="audio/xyz.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Please never just dump code as your answer without any explanation

Answer (score -1):

I would determine the width of the audio element (300px), create a container div surrounding the audio element and the H3 and then add `text-align: center` to the H3.

(You can remove the space separating the H3 from the line above it by removing the margin from the H3.)

You can see my edits below in the code snippet.

```css
.audio-container {
  width: 300px;
}

.audio-container h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<div class="audio-container">
  <h3>my <u><i>favourite</i></u> song ↓</h3>
  <br>
  <audio controls>
    <source
    src="audio/xyz.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: You don't need to make the h3's width 100%. It's a block level element, so it will always be 100% of its parent container **unless** you change the `display` property using CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I removed this from my answer